# In Javascript, what is the type/class of a (dynamically) imported ES6-Module instance?

Tags: javascript, module, es6-modules

After dynamically loading a module, i.e. after the corresponding promise has been resolved, one can act with a function or lambda-expression on the result. I was surprised to find that the module-instance (provided by the promise) does not have a prototype:

```
import("./module.js").then(x => {
    console.log(typeof x); // yields 'object' as expected
    console.log(x instanceof Object); // yields false !!
    console.log(x.__proto__); // yields undefined !!
    console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(x)); // yields null !!

    // but one can certainly access exported variables / functions
    x.exportedFunction();
})
```

Apparently, in spite of being an 'object', `x` does not seem to be an `Object` instance and does not seem to have any prototype at all. I wasn't aware that this is even possible. Firefox/Chrome and Safari all gave the same output (the one I spelled out in the code-comments). Is there an explanation? Is this specified anywhere? What kind of object is this module `x`?

**Note**: I'm not familiar with typescript, so I'm not sure if my question could be considered a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67923095/what-is-the-type-class-of-a-dynamically-imported-module-in-typescript)

**Edit**: I just realized that one obtains the same weird pseudo-object for statically imported modules into a namespace or [module object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#creating_a_module_object) via `import * as x from "./module.js"`. Although MDN mentions these objects they don't elaborate on what they are.

Comment: It seems that my confusion stems from my lack of understanding of the start of the prototype chain. I had assumed it starts with Object.prototype . But I've learned in the meantime, that there are more objects without prototype. In particular `Object.prototype.__proto__==null`and is therefore itself not an instance of `Object`. Also every Object created with `Object.create(null)` behaves the same as the module-object of my question. This is discussed in more length here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36692927/what-is-the-end-of-prototype-chain-in-javascript-null-or-object-prototype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a whole range of so called *[exotic objects](/q/31709156)*, which deviate from *[ordinary objects](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#ordinary-object)*. The type of an imported ES6-Module instance is one of these, the [Module Namespace Exotic Object](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#module-namespace-exotic-object):

> An object is a *module namespace exotic object* if its [[GetPrototypeOf]], [[SetPrototypeOf]], [[IsExtensible]], [[PreventExtensions]], [[GetOwnProperty]], [[DefineOwnProperty]], [[HasProperty]], [[Get]], [[Set]], [[Delete]], and [[OwnPropertyKeys]] internal methods use the definitions in this section, and its other essential internal methods use the definitions found in 10.1. These methods are installed by ModuleNamespaceCreate.

Why do `x instanceof Object`, `x.__proto__`, `Object.getPrototypeOf(x)` behave so weird? Let's look at the object's internal method that is involved here:

**GetPrototypeOf**

> The [[GetPrototypeOf]] internal method of a module namespace exotic
> object takes no arguments and returns a normal completion containing
> null. It performs the following steps when called:
>
> ```
> 1. Return null.
> ```

How are such objects created? There's a [special method](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-modulenamespacecreate) for that:

**ModuleNamespaceCreate ( module, exports )**

> The abstract operation ModuleNamespaceCreate takes arguments module (a
> Module Record) and exports (a List of Strings) and returns a module
> namespace exotic object. It is used to specify the creation of new
> module namespace exotic objects. It performs the following steps when
> called:
>
> ```
> 1. Assert: module.[[Namespace]] is empty.
> 2. Let internalSlotsList be the internal slots listed in Table 35.
> 3. Let M be MakeBasicObject(internalSlotsList).
> 4. Set M's essential internal methods to the definitions specified in 10.4.6.
> 5. Set M.[[Module]] to module.
> 6. Let sortedExports be a List whose elements are the elements of exports ordered as if an Array of the same values had been sorted using %Array.prototype.sort% using undefined as comparefn.
> 7. Set M.[[Exports]] to sortedExports.
> 8. Create own properties of M corresponding to the definitions in 28.3.
> 9. Set module.[[Namespace]] to M.
> 10. Return M.
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed, very helpful and fast answer! Just a tiny addendum:  
The specs you linked also contain another section about module-namespace
https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-module-namespace-objects
It mostly refers to the one you're citing, but also adds the following information:
_The initial value of the @@toStringTag property is the String value "Module"._
So if my namespace is `x`, one has
`x[Symbol.toStringTag]=="Module"`, which seems an easy way to test, if an object is a module namespace.

Comment: I just noticed that the above mentioned way of recognizing a module was the main topic of this [other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76448140/15983216) , so I thought I'd link it here.